# Running query of stored procedure belong to another database

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

I have a stored procedure in db A I Need to connect and use objects belong to database B is that possible ?

Comment: You need to define your requirements in much finer detail.  Use the [edit] feature to add details to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. You can reference the name of the database immediately prior to the `schema.tablename` like so...

```
From myDatabase.dbo.myTable
```

If you're doing this in dynamic sql you would set the db name into a variable and then use it like so...

```
Declare @dbName nvarchar (128)

SET @dbName = 'myDatabase'

exec ( '
Select  col01<br>
    ,   col02<br>
    ,   col03<br>
From    ' + @dbName + '.dbo.myTable;
'
```

There are also lots of other ways to do the same thing. For explanations I find this the simplest.

Hope this helps.

Comment: if I need to query the objects of db B
as :
use db b
select * from sys.objects how can i write it ?

Comment: @DANAA just prefix sys.objects with the database name.